# How to make margins of floating elements collapse

Tags: css, margin

How can I make the vertical margin of these floating divs collapse?

```css
.container {
  display: block;
  padding: 1px;
  max-width: 500px;
}

.float-left {
  display: block;
  float: left;
  margin: 20px;
}

.float-right {
  display: block;
  float: right;
  margin: 20px;
}

.center {
  display: block;
  text-align: center;
  margin: 20px;
}

.container * {
  outline: 2px solid red;
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 0px 20px rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="float-left">::::::::::::::::::::::FloatLeft::::::::::::::::::::::</div>
  <div class="float-right">::::::::::::::::::::::FloatRight::::::::::::::::::::::</div>
  <div class="center">::::::::::::::::::::::::::::Center::::::::::::::::::::::::::::</div>
</div>
```

Final result:

[image: final result]

Notice that the behavior of .float-left, .float-right and .center should be the same, when changing the width of .container, even if there is a solution without float.

Thank you.

Comment: By vertical margin do you man top and bottom margin?

Comment: Yes, of course.

Comment: It is not clear to me what you want to happen. If you do not want a top or bottom margin then just set them to 0. `margin-top: 0px`

Comment: @VincentRamdhanie I've added a second image with what I want to happen.

Comment: Why are you set on doing this with floats?

Comment: [This](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Box_Model/Mastering_margin_collapsing) is a good read: "Note that the margins of floating and absolutely positioned elements never collapse"

Comment: @AlexRummel Yes, I know, but how can I figure it out?

Comment: @cloned I do this with floats, because I dont know an other way. Do you? :)

Comment: There is a way to achieve this layout, although you would have to concede making the `center` element hug your two floated elements, which is an abnormal construct that I would probably advise against anyway. As you can't collapse margins of floating elements, though, I don't think your desired result is really possible with your current setup

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out:

```css
.container {
  display: block;
  padding: 10px;
  max-width: 500px;
}

.float-left {
  display: inline-block;
  float: left;
  margin: 10px;
}

.float-right {
  display: inline-block;
  float: right;
  margin: 10px;
}

.center {
  display: block;
  text-align: center;
}

.center_container {
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 10px;
}

body *:not(.center) {
  outline: 2px solid red;
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 0px 10px rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
}

body .container {
  box-shadow: inset 0px 0px 0px 10px rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="float-left">::::::::::::::::::::::FloatLeft::::::::::::::::::::::</div>
  <div class="float-right">::::::::::::::::::::::FloatRight::::::::::::::::::::::</div>
  <div class="center">
    <div class= "center_container">::::::::::::::::::::::::::::Center::::::::::::::::::::::::::::</div>
  </div>
</div>
```